# Open own screens from RootElement

Tags: ios, monotouch.dialog

I want to use Monotouch.Dialog for the first screen (after login in) that shows all the 'things' a user can do (just a simple grouped table style). I know I can achieve this very easily with Dialog, but I want to open my own screens when selecting an item (RootElement) from this list.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you nest the RootElements Monotouch.Dialog will automatically open the new screen when it is clicked. If you need more control over the process you can override `Selected` method and open the screen according to your needs.

Have a look at section 3.1 at [Introduction to MonoTouch.Dialog](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/monotouch.dialog)

Comment: Works perfectly ! Created my own RootElement with the Selected method overridden... Thx for the quick reply